# Making a key be pressed when another is unpressed (AHK)

Tags: key, autohotkey, auto

i am working on this script.

```
#Persistent
Random , timerval , 7800 , 8460
SetTimer, PressTheKey,  %timerval%
Return

PressTheKey:
Send, {d}
Return
```

This is a basic interval for "d" to be pressed every 8~ seconds. It works. The problem is, if another key is being pressed, like Right Mouse Button, "d" won't be triggered and i'll have to wait the remaining duration.

I need to make the script wait for right mouse button to be unpressed, or to run a check every 10ms or so to check if the right mouse button is pressed or not, and if it isn't, it could Send, {d}.

So, i was thinking of using GetKeyState(), KeyWait or a While Loop to get over that.

```
#Persistent
Random , timerval , 7800 , 8460
SetTimer, PressTheKey,  %timerval%
Return

GetKeyState, state, RButton
if state = D
KeyWait, RButton

PressTheKey:
Send, {d}
Return
```

I tried this one and the others but i was not able to put it to work, not a expert in coding, but im trying to learn.

Can someone help me with this?

edit: holding down the key for a certain amout of time fixes this.

```
#Persistent
Random , timerval , 7800 , 8460
Random , timerval2 , 180 , 250
SetTimer, PressTheKey,  %timerval%
Return

PressTheKey:
Send, {t down}
Sleep, %timerval2%
Send, {t up}
Return

F1::
Pause
Suspend
return
```

Answer (score 1):

GetKeyState will not work in your AHK example the reason is, it is not insite the loops.

(the first Return will prevent that)

you can fix this with this example:

Example.ahk

```
;#notrayicon
#SingleInstance force
#Persistent
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 10

Random , timerval , 7800 , 8460
SetTimer, PressTheKey,  %timerval%
Return



PressTheKey:
GetKeyState, state, RButton
if state = U
{
KeyWait, RButton
send {esc}
;ControlSend, , {esc}, ahk_exe NOTEPAD.EXE ;you can use this codeline for specific Application. 
}

Send, {d}
;ControlSend, , {d}, ahk_exe NOTEPAD.EXE ;you can use this codeline for specific Application. 
Return

f1::exitapp
```

note - if you do Right Mouse click then the Cursor will be disapear into the popup-menu you can **only** fix this with the code line `send {esc}` or write a code line to focus cursor back to that window!

Comment: thanks for the heads up. unfortunately that still doesn't seem to work. Maybe if the script could send RButton up when the timer triggers, even if the mouse is phisically pressed.

Comment: @Frederico Cintra Torres - The Code Line `if state = D` stands for Down and If you want to use Up you can use the Code line `if state = U` **note - if you do Right Mouse click then the Cursor will be disapear into the popup-menu you can need/fix this with the code line `send {esc}`**- i will change my answer and i hope you will like it

Comment: thanks for giving it a try, i tried it and it didn't work, probably just the way the program runs. i managed to fix it by simply making the press a Hold, i edited my original post with it.

Answer (score 0):

You nearly had it.

```
#Persistent
Random , timerval , 7800 , 8460
SetTimer, PressTheKey,  %timerval%
Return

PressTheKey:
KeyWait, RButton, U
Send, {d}
Return
```

The only problem I can see is if the `RButton` is held down for longer than 2x the timer. In that case, I believe it will only trigger one extra `Send, {d}` as opposed to the total amount that it should. Anyway, that seems like an unlikely situation based on what you've said.

Comment: It didn't? What did it do? For me, it sent a `d` immediately after releasing the `RButton` if it was held when it should have sent `d` and then resumed the timing.

Comment: i think it has to do with the way the program works. it rejects the new key if it is an instant click, but if i hold the key for a small duration, it works.

Comment: Ah, I see. I've found that sometimes `SendEvent` behaves better than `SendInput`, especially with games. You may want to give that a try as that would eliminate the need to have the key held down for an interval.